# Ubuntu 22.04, php downgrade from 8.1 to 7.4 broke phpmyadmin. Tried everrything so far

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-22.04, php-7.4

I am trying to deploy an old Laravel 5.6 project on AWS and encountered an issue with phpMyAdmin. It was working fine before, but after downgrading to PHP 7.4 to match the requirements for the Laravel project, phpMyAdmin stopped working. The following error message appears on the page: "This page isn't working." I have searched for a solution but have been unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: you have to downgrade phpmyadmin to a version that support php7.4.

Comment: Thank you @LelioFaieta for replying. How to downgrade, not able to find anything?

Comment: how did you install it? as an ubuntu package?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I installed it as ubuntu package
sudo apt install phpmyadmin

Comment: Look for your php error log and post it here to provide some more details. I think PhpMyadmin should work fine on php 7.4. I would also advice to install PhpMyAdmin on a different server and or isolated site as those are 2 different applications with there own needs and security considerations.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? It can be seen through apt with `dpkg -l phpmyadmin`.